# Run java executable at start up (LMDE 2 Betsy)

Tags: java, linux, startup, linux-mint, autostart

I'm trying to run a jar file after startup. I created a blabla.sh file within /etc/init.d

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: blabla
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop: $local_fs
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: blablashort
# Description: blablalong
### END INIT INFO

cd /home/myUser/Dokumente/blablaFolder/
java -jar blablaJar.jar
```

After creating this file,

```
chmod +x blabla.sh
```

and

```
sudo update-rc.d blabla.sh defaults
```

but the jar does not start. The jar file should start in full screen.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Do you have any logs or error message, so we can help you?

Comment: The script runs if i execute it manually. If I reboot I get: ```[warn] VirtualBox Additions disabled, not in a Virtual Machine ... (warning). [Fail] startpar: service(s) returned failure: blabla.sh plymouth ... fail```